# C++ pointers and objects

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having a hard time with `*` and `&` in the following code:

Declare variable and call function:

```
SDL_Event event;
myfunc(event);
```

Function:

```
void MyApp::myfunc(SDL_Event* event) {
    while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) ) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) { 
            // ...
        }
    } 
}
```

Compiler:
error: no matching function for call to 'MyApp::myfunc(SDL_Event&)'
note: candidates are: void MyApp::myfunc(SDL_Event*)|

What am  I doing wrong and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you improve upon your question title so that it actually describes the question, please.

Answer (score 5):

#### First error: pointers and objects

You need to call myfunc with a *pointer* to a SLD_Event object, instead of calling with the SLD_Event object itself:

```
myfunc(&event);
```

Putting a `&` in front of a object (or variable) tells the compiler that you want the memory address of the object (which is the so called pointer to it).

Putting a `*` in front of a pointer to an object tells the compiler that you want the content of the memory address to which the pointer points (which is the object or variable itself)

The compiler error you get, tells that the compiler is not able to find a function with the name myfunc that accepts a (reference to) an SLD_Event object. Which is correct since the (only) myfunc function available requires a pointer to a SLD_Event object as its argument.

#### Second error: pointers to pointers

The second (independent to the first one) compiler error (`error: cannot convert 'SDL_Event**' to 'SDL_Event*' for argument '1' to 'int SDL_PollEvent(SDL_Event*)'`) you got, tells that the variable type you put into the `SLD_PollEvent` function is incompatible with the expected typeand it could not be converted automatically.

Because you added a `&` before the `event` variable in that function call, you are basically asking to get the pointer to the memory location which points the the event object. The is perfectly legal C code, but not what you want, because the `SLD_EventPoll` function expect the pointer the the event object (which has the type `SLD_Event *`).

So to solve your second error change the line into:

```
while ( SDL_PollEvent(event) ) {
```

(notice the removed `&`)

#### Third error: Addressing object variables in (pointers to) objects

The third error in your code is the `event.type`. Because event is a pointer the the `SLD_Event` object, C++ expects a `->` instead of the `.` (which is used for objects, ie `SLD_Event` without the `*`).

Comment: I've tried that, but the compiler responds with: `error: cannot convert 'SDL_Event**' to 'SDL_Event*' for argument '1' to 'int SDL_PollEvent(SDL_Event*)'` ?

Comment: @Ben - See the second part of my answer, it covers that part.

Comment: @Ben, this is a different error. So you solved the first one, now you need to solve the second one.

Comment: Updated my answer for a second and a third error (sorry, for the third error there is not extensive description, as it is just a definition and there is no deeper meaning behind the difference between `.` and `->` as far as I know. Except for the pointer/object difference)

Answer (score 4):

The `*` in the function definition means that it takes the address of an `SDL_Event`.  So you need to give it one:

```
SDL_Event event;
myfunc(&event);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `myfunc()` method takes a pointer to an `SDL_Event` (i.e. an `SDL_Event*`), not an `SDL_Event` instance.  Try doing:

```
SDL_Event event;
myfunc(&event);
```

Also note that unless `SDL_PollEvent()` expects a parameter of type `SDL_Event**` you do not need the `&` there.  You can just do:

```
while ( SDL_PollEvent(event) ) {

    if (event->type == SDL_QUIT) { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

...since you already have a pointer to the `SDL_Event`.  Also note that I have replaced your `event.type` with `event->type` (also valid is `(*event).type`).  Because `event` is a pointer at this point, the only way to access the `type` field of the actual `SDL_Event` instance is to dereference the pointer first.  This is what the `->` and `*` operators do for you.

Comment: Thank you! I kept getting errors before, but now with the `->` it works :)

Answer (score 1):

you also need to dereference the pointer:

```
if (event->type == SDL_QUIT) { 
    // ...
}
```

and i don't know, but i guess SDL_PollEvent also takes a pointer, so that would be:

```
SDL_PollEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see:

First, you're not passing myFunc a pointer, which it expects by your definition.  You should either:

1. Declare event as a pointer OR
2. Pass the address of event to myFunc using &event.

Second problem is:

```
while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
```

Your parameter called event is a pointer.  The Address-of opertor (&) is not necessary to pass the pointer to SDL_PollEvent.  Actually, if SDL_PollEvent is expecting a pointer, it's wrong to use address-of in this context.  event already IS a pointer.  By using address-of, you're saying the address of the pointer, or a pointer to a pointer.